# Match a string which is few lines above another line where the first string was matched

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have this text file which is huge. I need to look for a string and when I match it, I need to go a few lines back(above the current line) and search for another string and extract some information from that line that contains the second string. How can I do this in Python using regex match? 
I am trying to do something like this.

```
substr1 = re.compile("ACT",re.IGNORECASE)
substr2 = re.compile(vector,re.IGNORECASE) 

try:
    with open (filepath, 'rt') as in_file:  
        for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):   
            if substr2.search(line) != None:
                print(linenum,line)

                    # Code to trace back a few lines to look for substr1

                break
except FileNotFoundError:                   # If the file not found,
    print("pattern not found.")                # print an error message.
```

It is kind of like I want to read it backward when I match the first string and look for the first occurrence of the second string. The number of lines varies and I cannot thus use the dequeue option I think. I am totally new to Python. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you!
Am adding an example log file that I am reading.

```
X 123  
X 1234  
X 12345  
Vector1  
----  
-----  
-----  
X 1231  
X 12344  
X 123456  
vector a  
vector b  
vector c  
vector d  
-------  
-------  
Vector  
----  
-----  
-----  
X 1233  
X 12345  
X 123451  
Vector2
```

String 1 : `Vector`
String 2 : `X`

Output should be `X 123456`

Comment: What are the bounds on "a few"?

Comment: Also, what is `vector`? What is stopping you from searching for `substr1`, then looking a few lines down for `substr2`?

Comment: a few would be about 100 lines(varies depending on where vector is located), vector is the first string i am looking for.. I should then find the second string which is above(not down) this line that contains vector.

Comment: Can you give a sample of vector? I still don't understand why you don't just search in the other order. If the second match is not found, keep going.

Comment: Is there a *hard* upper bound on "few" though? Can I say for example that it will *never* occur more than 200 lines beore?

Comment: vector is just a string. Like, I need to trace a few lines back in order to find information about the vector from the logs. I cannot do that in order as there are multiple entries of the second string. So for reference, I need to first find vector and then look for the associated string and stop the search at its first occurrence. Hope that makes sense ...

Comment: @wonder: must you use regex? It's easier to iterate through the file searching for the first pattern then the second pattern using the `in` operator.

Comment: @mhawke. That really does not make the slightest difference for the issue at hand, although `in` will be faster.

Comment: It would be great if I can do some kind of reverse search from the current line I am at(which has the first string) and then stop at the first occurrence of the second string. i do not know if 200 would work..

Comment: @MadPhysicist:   Well it requests clarification from the OP regarding the use of regex which is messy in this case vs. a simple Pythonic solution that is easy to implement and understand. It makes a big difference.

Comment: Final question: what output are you looking for? Line numbers (judging by the fact that you are retaining them)?

Comment: Line numbers are not much to use to me, I was intending to remove them. I will need to extract some content from the line containing the second string. That is why I was using regex.

Comment: I have added an example log.. please help.

Comment: @wonder. Your problem description is very imprecise. From the log you have shown, it appears that you want an exact case sensitive match of string 1 and a partial match of string 2? And what you are looking for is the match of string 2? Please edit your question to be consistent between the narrative and example sections. Don't reply to this in the comments.

Comment: @wonder. Also, please fix your notation. It seems like you switch between "first" meaning first in the file and first found a number of times. Could you be consistent. Perhaps call it "top string" and "bottom string". Make your variables "substr_top" and "substr_bottom" to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to backtrack. Instead, just search forward in a smarter manner. If you search for `substr1` first, the only issue that could happen is that more occurrences of `substr1` will be found before you find `substr2`. The way to handle that is to keep updating match of `substr1` as you go.

From your description, it does not appear that you need regex at all. Instead, you appear to be looking for simple string containment tests.

```
substr1 = 'X'
substr2 = 'Vector'

with open (filepath, 'rt') as in_file:
    matched = None
    for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file, start=1):
        if substr1 in line:
            matched = line
        elif matched and line == substr2:
            # Process the second string
            print(matched)
            break
```

If you have whitespace at the end of your lines, as you do in the sample you give, you may want to use `line.startswith(substr2)` instead of `line == substr2`.

Minor fixes:

- `start=1` will make your line numbers start with 1, which is probably what you want.
- If you want to compare against `None`, the proper way is `is not None` instead of `!=`. Additionally, `regex.search` returns a match object. It will always be truthy if a match occurs. The idiomatic way to check it is without even `is not None`.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. The logic must work, I need to do regex on the line that contains substr1. Not substr2.

Comment: @wonder. I have done my best to update. The current code is tested with the input you provide to give the output you provide. Please fix your question though. The more I read it, the harder it is to understand.

Comment: Thank you @madphysicist that worked just fine. I am really sorry if I couldn't convey the problem well. I meant the top string as string 2 and the bottom one as string 1. I will update it. Thank you, I appreciate it. I am a newbie in this forum and it is really wonderful to know how people are helping others out!